# Битрикс 24 и Google spreadsheets: как автоматически выгрузить сделки (со всеми полями) за последние 6 месяцев в Google-таблицу

Tags: битрикс, google-apps-script, битрикс24, google-spreadsheet

**Задача - загрузить из битрикс 24 через хук все сделки со всеми полями и значениями за последние 6 месяцев (для углубленного анализа) в google-таблицу.**

Ниже у меня есть примерный шаблон функции для формирования post запроса. Не факт что он работает корректно, но это единственное что нашел на данный момент.

**Как и какие данные надо отправить в запросе чтобы получить список сделок с полями и значениями.** 
*Как распарсить ответ и записать его в таблицу я знаю.*

```
function getDealList(){

  var data = {
     "param1": [{" ": " "}],
     "param2": [{" ": " " }]
    };

   var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : data //JSON.stringify(data) ?
  }; 

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://infoplus.bitrix24.ru/rest/54/'+ hookKey +'/crm.deal.add', options);
   var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
   Logger.log(dataAll);
}
```

Comment: У вас задача, вы и делайте. Ознакомьтесь с правилами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking Причем тут хуки и выгрузка истории?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var data = {
   'filter': {'ID': 15},
   'order': {"ID":"DSС"},
   // 'select': ['ID','DATE_CREATE','CLOSEDATE','UTM_SOURCE','OPPORTUNITY']};
```

//использовать метод crm.deal.list